# C# Parsing JSON String

Tags: c#, json

I have tried countless methods to Parse my JSON string (Steam Public Data), yet nothing seems to work. I just want to be able to extract values from the string. For Example, obtaining the value of `personaname` which would return `SlothGod`. I have JSON.NET installed in my project.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198301407459",
                "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
                "profilestate": 1,
                "personaname": "SlothGod",
                "lastlogoff": 1508389707,
                "commentpermission": 1,
                "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/sleuthgud/",
                "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/09/09cea52b91136fb3306c57771a746db2823b91ba.jpg",
                "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/09/09cea52b91136fb3306c57771a746db2823b91ba_medium.jpg",
                "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/09/09cea52b91136fb3306c57771a746db2823b91ba_full.jpg",
                "personastate": 0,
                "realname": "Josh",
                "primaryclanid": "103582791460168790",
                "timecreated": 1462086929,
                "personastateflags": 0,
                "loccountrycode": "AU",
                "locstatecode": "QLD"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Main method suggested to me:

```
public class Details
{
    public string personaname { get; set; }
}
private void GetSteamDetails()
{
    var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details>(SteamDetailsJson);
    SteamName = data.personaname;
}
```

This is placed before Page_Load(). I then call GetSteamDetails(); when I want to fetch the name.

Comment: You should show what you have tried.. and we can try and help fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I have looked at that exact post myself, yet I was never able to get it working

Comment: not clear question. provide what you tried so far and where exactly you are facing problem.

Comment: OP should first study how to parse JSON in c#. The complexity level of JSON parsing is really low specially with the right tools and valid format.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado Trust me, I have been studying it, but I just can't seem to understand it, and the easiest way to learn something is by having an example show to you that you actually understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After my question being down voted, I decided to not give up on this problem. After extensive research, trial and error, and YouTube tutorials which are the most helpful IMO. I found that the data was containing a JSON array, and yes I will admit, I was confused with this, but the answer was to simply treat it like a C# array and add [1] to the end of players.

```
Details details = new Details();
public class Details
{
    public string avatar { get; set; }
    public string avatarmedium { get; set; }
    public string avatarfull { get; set; }
    public string realname { get; set; }
    public string personaname { get; set; }
    public string steamid { get; set; }
}

private void GetSteamDetails()
{
    var SteamDetails= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(SteamDetailsJson);
    avatar = SteamDetails.response.players[1].avatar.ToString();
    personaname = SteamDetails.response.players[1].personaname.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the JSON string you provided, you should have the following C# classes to support it, or to deserialize the JSON object values into:  I used [this](http://json2csharp.com/) link to generate the classes.

```
public class Player
{
    public string steamid { get; set; }
    public int communityvisibilitystate { get; set; }
    public int profilestate { get; set; }
    public string personaname { get; set; }
    public int lastlogoff { get; set; }
    public int commentpermission { get; set; }
    public string profileurl { get; set; }
    public string avatar { get; set; }
    public string avatarmedium { get; set; }
    public string avatarfull { get; set; }
    public int personastate { get; set; }
    public string realname { get; set; }
    public string primaryclanid { get; set; }
    public int timecreated { get; set; }
    public int personastateflags { get; set; }
    public string loccountrycode { get; set; }
    public string locstatecode { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<Player> players { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using `Newtonsoft.Json`, you can deserialize the JSON object into your C# classes as follow:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("yourJsonString");
```

Answer (score 2):

You mention that `Newtonsoft.Json` already referenced in the project.

Use class to represent json data structure, then you can easy deserialize it.
You can use only properties you need in the class.

```
public class Player
{
    public string personaname { get; set; } 
}

var player = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(jsonString);

// use player.personaname
```

For updates question create classes which represent your data structure

```
public class Team
{
    public List<Player> players { get; set; } 
}

public class Response
{
    public Team response { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I have been very confused about the DeserializeObject method, would you be able to explain what I add in place of `Data`?

Comment: Create class `Data` or name it how you want.

Comment: I edited my question and added the changes that I made. SteamName is still returning null.

Comment: No very nice to edit questions this way, but simply you need to create classes which represents your data structure - you can use some online converters from json to c# classes - just search for "json to c# class"

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate a class automatically from a JSON string.

Comment: I dont know why people down voted this answer ? This is a good one.

Comment: I am not downvoter, but I think because "link" answers not very welcome on SO

Comment: @Fabio I suspect that's why. That page goes down and this answer is useless. It's better as an aside to an existing answer.

Comment: I did downvote that answer because the OP is trying to convert in runtime. The question is not "How to write a C# class based on a JSON string". I bet he can write his classes by himself.