# How to get value from JSON objects in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I've tried to get the values from the JSON object that I made a request from Google APIs. My goal is to get the data from transcript.

This is the JSON file.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "how old are you",
          "confidence": 0.66882694
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I've tried to get the output by using this. But it doesn't work.

```
var result = ["result"][0]["alternative"][0]["transcript"].ToString()
```

When I query the data, It doesn't show anything, just empty string.

Comment: Your key can't match with your json.

Comment: Where are you storing your JSON object. You need to work on that object. Have you Googled "parsing a JSON string in C#"

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823946/c-sharp-parsing-json-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION (without using external library like NewtonSoft.Json):**

- Add reference **System.Web.Extensions**.
- use an assembly **System.Web.Script.Serialization;**

**CODE:**

```
var jsonString = "{\"results\": [ {\"alternatives\": [ {\"transcript\": \"how old are you\", \"confidence\": 0.66882694 } ] }  ]}";
var jsonDeserialized = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic> (jsonString);
Console.WriteLine (jsonDeserialized["results"][0]["alternatives"][0]["transcript"]); // Prints "how old are you"
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Convert your JSON to a class

[`Json2CSharp`](http://json2csharp.com/) and you get:

```
public class Alternative
{
    public string transcript { get; set; }
    public double confidence { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Alternative> alternatives { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

Store it somewhere in your code.

#### Use Newtonsoft.Json package

Install [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) NUGet Package in your solution and import it in your code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Now you can deserialize your json as you prefer as long as you have it in a `string` variable.

```
var yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

You may access your `transcript` value using:

```
var transcript = yourObject.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your strings are JSON formatted, so you will need to parse it into a object. For that you can use JSON.NET.

Here is an example on how to parse a JSON string into a dynamic object:

```
string source = "{\r\n   \"id\": \"100000280905615\", \r\n \"name\": \"Jerard Jones\",  \r\n   \"first_name\": \"Jerard\", \r\n   \"last_name\": \"Jones\", \r\n   \"link\": \"https://www.facebook.com/Jerard.Jones\", \r\n   \"username\": \"Jerard.Jones\", \r\n   \"gender\": \"female\", \r\n   \"locale\": \"en_US\"\r\n}";
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(source);
Console.WriteLine(data.id);
.
```

Console which data you want show

Answer (score 1):

Usually if I knew what the structure of the JSON looks like I would use class to parse it.

But you could always parse the string to JSON object anytime.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var json=JObject.Parse(YOUR_JSON_STRING)
var result = json["results"][0]["alternative"][0]["transcript"].ToString()
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/KSDcIP

Also your keys that you are requesting doesn't match the keys in the JSON